# Read from API JSON using Alamofire Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

i have hard time to read JSON using Alamofire. below is the structure of  the API response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "order": {
            "id": 258,
            "created_at": "2018-07-01T14:51:05+08:00",
            "user_id": "1234"
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "transaction_type": "rent",
                "cabinet_id": "02110A0000C6",
                "jack_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Basically, i need to print out only the array  of `transactions` and also print one by one the `transaction_type`, `cabinet_id`, and `jack_id`
The previous one i just manage to print the api response using code below

```
        Alamofire.request(WalletRouter.urlUserActiveOrder(id: userId)).responseJSON { response in

            if let value = response.result.value {

                let dict = value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                //print (value)
                if let innerDict = dict!["data"]  {
                    print (innerDict) //manage to return the value

          let data = innerDict["transactions"] as! NSArray //get error here

                                            print (data)
                }

            }
            //do your json stuff
         else if (response.result.isFailure) {
            //Manager your error
            switch (response.error!._code){
            case NSURLErrorTimedOut:
                //Manager your time out error
                break
            case NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
                //Manager your not connected to internet error
                break
            default:
                print ("error")

            }
        }
    }
```

i have already spent 6 hour to solve this, but still failed to get the value.

Comment: Please (learn to) read the JSON. It's very simple. There are only two collection types, array (`[]` -> Swift `[[String:Any]]`, **not** `NSArray`) and dictionary (`{}` -> Swift `[String:Any]`, **not** `NSDictionary`). So check the type of the value for key `data`. There are hundreds of related question and answers here on SO.

Comment: In other words, `innerDict` isn't a dictionary.

Comment: In addition: It can be really helpful to use Decodable-Protocol for reading JSON. But this always depends on your needs... you can check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable

Answer (score -1):

Create a struct class like below

```
 struct Result: Decodable {
     struct data12: Decodable {
          struct transaction: Decodable {
            let transactionType:String
            let cabinetId:String
            let jackId:Int
        }
        let transactions:[transaction]
      }
     let data:[data12]
}
```

Data fetching like this

```
  do {
            let data1 = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: [])
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
           let courses = try decoder.decode(Result.self, from: data1)
             print(courses)
         } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

if anyOne think my approach is wrong please update my answer TIA

Comment: This is Swift: No `NSArray`, no `NSDictionary`, no `NSNumber`, no `value(forKey`, no `.mutableLeaves`, no variable names with starting capital letter, no carelessly forced unwrapping.

Comment: Don't force unwrapping (all the "!"). Avoid using NSStuff in Swift3+, prefers Swift equivalent (NSArray, NSDictionary => Array, Dictionary, etc.). I don't recommend `value(forKey:)` for debutants, it could be misleading. `let Dict = `, don't name your var starting with an uppercase. You do a `try`, is there a `catch`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply(@vadian, @larme), i realised how to work on swift3+ , i updated my code.

Comment: @vadian i updated my code i hope this is the correct approach